# Change picture module image style programmatically

Tags: views, display-suite, media

I am using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) and [picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/picture) module to display a page containing products (teaser) and I have 2 layouts: with 3 columns and with 6 columns. 
Based on the layout, I want to change the image style (I have 2 image styles... say "Product thumbnail small" and "Product thumbnail large"), so the images are bigger when using the 3 columns layout and smaller when using the 6 columns layout.

I tried using hook_picture (the code below) to alter the picture array and use the original theme_picture function to render the image, but it seems it has no effect.

I also tried to change the image style from the ds page for the teaser, but again, it has no effect.

```
function vine_picture($item)
{
    if ('product_thumbnail' == $item['style_name']) {
        static $view;

        if (empty($view)) {
            $view = views_get_current_view();
        }

        if (!empty($view) && 3 == $view->style_plugin->options['columns']) {
            $item['breakpoints']['breakpoints.theme.vine.medium']['1x']['image_style'] = 'product_thumbnail_large_breakpoints_theme_vine_medium_1x';
            $item['breakpoints']['breakpoints.theme.vine.small']['1x']['image_style'] = 'product_thumbnail_large_breakpoints_theme_vine_small_1x';
        }
    }

    return theme_picture($item);
}
```

Comment: Although only somewhat related, I was able to do this on a node by using `hook_node_view()` and a snippet like so: `$node->content['field_image'][0]['#breakpoints'][$name][$multiplier]['image_style'] = 'my_new_image_style_name';`